# dialog box with radio button and validate button

Tags: android

[image]
I want to add a button centered below the two radio second radio button B and when i checked an option and click on validate, an action take place. Any help please

```
final CharSequence[] photo = {"A","B"};

AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

alert.setTitle("Select Gender");

alert.setSingleChoiceItems(photo,-1, new 

DialogInterface.OnClickListener()

{

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
    {
        if(photo[which]=="A")

        {

            gen="B";
        }

        else if (photo[which]=="B")

        {

            gen="B";

        }
    }

});
alert.show();
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> My method making Custom dialog

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application reference from here

1. Create one xml custom dialog

   > ```
   >    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   >     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   >     android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
   >
   >     <RadioButton
   >         android:id="@+id/rd_!"
   >         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   >         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   >         android:text="A" />
   >
   >     <RadioButton
   >         android:id="@+id/rd_2"
   >         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   >         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   >         android:layout_below="@+id/rd_!"
   >         android:text="B" />
   >
   >     <Button
   >         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   >         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   >         android:layout_below="@+id/rd_2"
   >         android:layout_centerInParent="true"
   >         android:text="OK" />
   >     </RelativeLayout>
   > ```

and activity.java file

```
  Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Dialogeshow.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialoge);
    dialog.setTitle("This is my custom dialog box");
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    // there are a lot of settings, for dialog, check them all out!
    // set up radiobutton
    RadioButton rd1 = (RadioButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.rd_);
    RadioButton rd2 = (RadioButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.rd_2);

    // now that the dialog is set up, it's time to show it
    dialog.show();
```

Comment: You should add your RadioButtons to RadioGroup in xml file.

Comment: how to add onclicklistener

Comment: @HarishReddy For the listeners:

RadioButton rd1 = (RadioButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.rd_1);
                                rd1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @ Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                    }
                                });

Answer (score 17):

Try to do this, you just have to select the default selection and add to the dialog an integer -> `inputSelection`

```
final CharSequence[] items = { " HDMI IN ", " AV IN" };

        // Creating and Building the Dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Select Input Type");

        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items,inputSelection,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        inputSelection = item;
                        levelDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        levelDialog = builder.create();
        levelDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use below method to show dialog

```
public void showDialog(Context context, String title, String[] btnText,
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener) {

    final CharSequence[] items = { "One", "Two" };

    if (listener == null)
        listener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface,
                    int paramInt) {
                paramDialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        };
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle(title);

    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                }
            });
    builder.setPositiveButton(btnText[0], listener);
    if (btnText.length != 1) {
        builder.setNegativeButton(btnText[1], listener);
    }
    builder.show();
}
```

And the calling part can be done as below:

```
showDialog(MainActivity.this, "Your Title", new String[] { "Ok" },
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            if(which==-1)
            Log.d("Neha", "On button click");
            //Do your functionality here
        }
    });
```

Comment: i wonder how can i checked if a radio button is checked with your solution

Comment: when i called it both which value is -1

Comment: Can you please explain how the circle shows green when we select the item in this code?? and can we directly call this alert dialog in onClick listener of some view without this showDialog method?? I tried this but the circle dose not show selected.  @Neha Dhanwani

Comment: you can add this line: int selectedPosition = ((AlertDialog)dialog).getListView().getCheckedItemPosition();

Comment: The solution as it is not working and always which=-1. Have you tested this code and got the correct selected item ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a single button to your dialog using `Builder.setNeutralButton`.

Comment: but how to select a radio option only on button click

Comment: please refer this site http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/alert-dialog-window-with-radio-buttons-in-android/

Comment: @peter your solution does not support froyo 2.2

Comment: @sophia in androidmanifest  file minsdk set as 8 and run your code:)

Comment: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
don't change anything

Comment: @sophia in that URL they are using fragment concept. fragment supports version 3+. so please try other option http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.in/2011/03/how-to-display-alertdialog-and.html